# Is there a way to restore an Akeeba database backup through the admin?

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup

I'm using Akeeba to backup my database (database only, I'm not backing up files). I haven't been able to find a way to restore only the database using the admin. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to restore a backup of the database (.sql file) using Akeeba Backups itself. To restore the database, you must import it using PhpMyAdmin or a similar tool. If you do not have access to PhpMyAdmin on your server then an alternative would be using this:

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Or a Backup and Restore extension for Joomla:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/665

Hope this helps

Comment: ok, thanks. We've been using the command line and its been working fine, but that would be a useful extension to have, I'll look into those other extensions

Comment: Personally I have never used and never will use an extension to backup my sites. It's simply another extension to add to the list which is not needed. I find it so easy simply going to the File Manager, zipping everything up and downloading it. For the database backup, I can either do this via PhpMyAdmin or one of cPanel's built in tools. Restoring is so simply. Just upload and extract or in the case of the database, upload via PhpMyAdmin et voila.

Comment: Once you've used Akeeba to back up nightly to amazon s3 and them used kickstart pro to restore to a new server from s3 with no downloading/uploading you'll never go back :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Akeeba Backup *Pro* then this is probably the solution:

1. Go to Akeeba Backup Pro
2. Go to Profiles Managment
3. Click on New and use the Profile name e.g. MySQL Restoration
4. Now go Back to the Akeeba Backup Pro Control Panel
5. Switch you Profile to "MySQL Restoration"
6. Then click on "Files and Directories Exclusion"
7. Exclude now every File and Directory beside the index.php file
8. Now make a Backup with this new Profile
9. Then go "Manage Backups" and choose last Backup and click on restore
10. Now follow instructions
11. Done